# how to sort array of dictionaries in ios

Tags: ios, sorting, nsarray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have dict formate like this. I need to sort array by using "quantity1" key inside dict key of dictionary.

```
array: (
{
  brand = Ryul;
  productTitle = Any;
  quantity = 1;
  subBrand = "Ryul INJ";
  type = Product;
  dict = {
         brand1 = Trol;
         productTitle1 = Different;
         quantity1 = 2;
         subBrand1 = "";
         type1 = Brand;
      };
},
{
  brand = Trol;
  productTitle = Different;
  quantity = 2;
  subBrand = "";
  type = Brand;
  dict = {
         brand1 = Trol;
         productTitle1 = Different;
         quantity1 = 2;
         subBrand1 = "";
         type1 = Brand;
      };
 }
)
```

I used this code for sorting:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"quantity"  ascending:YES];
    stories=[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
   recent = [stories copy];
```

This is working when i used the key "quantity". But it is not working when i used the key "quantity1".

How i will sort? help me

Answer (score 11):

using

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dict.quantity1"  ascending:YES];
stories=[stories sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];
```

the key is dict. quantity1

Comment: @HariBabu you should credit Suen for helping resolve your issue if they did just that.